# 'this' inside View.render() being set to the model

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am new to Backbone.js

I must be doing something wrong here. I'm trying to make a little demo to see what I can do with Backbone and basing it off some sample code.

I an get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method `toJSON` of undefined".

I see why it is doing this, because the `.bind("change", taskView.render)` call is setting the context to the model (which the alert confirms) but it seems like there should at least be an argument to the render function to get access to the view. Maybe I am just going about it the wrong way? (see the sample code below).

```
task.bind("change", _.bind(taskView.render, taskView));
```

Comment: Use [listenTo](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Backbone Views and Models, the 'this' context for 'bind' is the calling object, so for `model.bind('change', ...)` `this` with be the model. For `view.bind(...` `this` will be the view.

You are getting the error because `task.bind("change", _.bind(taskView.render, taskView));` sets `this` to be task when render runs, but `this` actually needs to be taskView.

Since you want to bind the model event to the view, as irvani suggests, the best way to do this is to use the `.listenTo` method (see: http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo)

```
taskView.listenTo(task, 'change', taskView.render);
```

Depending on how you want the view lifecycle to work, you could also put the code in the `initialize` method of the view, which executes when the view is created. Then use `stopListening` in the `remove` method, to clear up the listener when the view is no longer in use.

As the task model is passed into the view, you get a fairly neat:

```
AskView = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
    },
    ...
    remove: function(){
        this.stopListening(this.model);
        ...
    }
 });

 var askView = new AskView({ model: task });
```

However, the one line solution to your problem is:

```
 task.on("change", taskView.render, taskView);
```

`bind` is just an alias of `on` (see: http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on). The first argument is the event you are listening to, the second is the method to fire, and the third argument is the context to bind to, in this case, your taskView.

Answer (score 0):

```
task.listenTo(model, 'change', taskView.render);
```

This says that listen to the model change and render the taskView on every change.

Comment: (1) Quoting and referencing the [`listenTo` documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) would help them learn why they should be using `listenTo`. (2) [`on` (AKA `bind`)](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on) takes an optional third `context` argument if they want to stick with `on` for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

As irvani suggested, use [**`listenTo`**](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) instead.

> `object.listenTo(other, event, callback)`  Tell an object to listen to a particular event on an other object. The advantage of using this
>   form, instead of other.on(event, callback, object), is that listenTo
>   allows the object to keep track of the events, and they can be removed
>   all at once later on. **The callback will always be called with object
>   as context**.

In your case,

```
taskView.listenTo(task,"change",taskView.render);
```

assuming taskView is `Backbone.View` and `task` is a `Backbone.Model`.

The chances of memory leaks will be less when you use `listenTo` compared to using `on`.

---

If you must use [`on`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on), you can specify the context as a third argument as and mu is too short suggested:

> To supply a context value for this when the callback is invoked, pass the optional last argument: `model.on('change', this.render, this)` or `model.on({change: this.render}, this)`.

In your case:

```
task.on("change", taskView.render, taskView);
```